# Forecast Assistance given Monthly Time Series Data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, dynamic-regression

I'm looking for some help to determine what type of model I should use for the given data set:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 
15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 
16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 
16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 
17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 
17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 
18567, 18597, 18628, 18659, 18687, 18718, 18748, 18779, 18809, 
18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18962, 18993, 19024, 19052, 19083, 
19113, 19144, 19174), class = "Date"), refined_petroleum_index = c(305.2, 
323.1, 302.1, 288.2, 284.8, 286.6, 286.6, 294.2, 290, 290.4, 
289.3, 296.5, 298, 298.9, 296.8, 295.5, 289.1, 288.7, 284.3, 
284.6, 275.3, 258.4, 249, 213.6, 172, 176.9, 185.5, 175.4, 196.1, 
197.2, 194.3, 183.6, 161, 160.7, 160.8, 144.8, 132.1, 119.5, 
125.8, 131.9, 141, 151.8, 151.1, 145.2, 149.8, 158.2, 155.1, 
162.4, 174.4, 174.8, 169.7, 170.2, 158.8, 156.5, 158.5, 169.4, 
184.7, 185.5, 194.7, 200.8, 205.9, 209.8, 202.3, 208.5, 215.6, 
220.6, 218, 220.6, 221.9, 232.5, 214.4, 191.1, 174.4, 186.2, 
200.3, 212.6, 206.3, 191, 194.6, 191.1, 187.6, 195, 192.1, 200, 
198.5, 185.3, 148.9, 91.5, 94.5, 122.6, 140.7, 147.4, 143, 146, 
148.4, 171.3, 186.2, 207.4, 226.1, 223.9, 230.9, 237.4, 246.455, 
248.072, 255.587, 277.508, 278.616, 270.678, 287.284, 324.794, 
366.333, 380.416, 402.415, 455.191, 391.24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-115L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the decomposition of the data:
[image]

Based on the seasonality in the decomposition, I believe that there is definitely yearly, maybe half a year seasonality, and quarterly data.

I have tried to building the following models:

```
hw_model <- hw(tsclean(training_hw), seasonal = "additive", h = length(validation_hw), initial = "optimal")
```

A Holt Winters' model with additive seasonality

```
dh_regression<- dhReg::dhr(training, XREG = NULL, Range =list(1:6), Frequency = 12, Criteria = "bic", maxp = 5,
    maxq = 5, maxd = 5)
```

A dynamic harmonic regression model with fourier orders 1-6.

```
harmonics <- fourier(tsclean(training), K = 6)
arima_model <- auto.arima(tsclean(training), seasonal = TRUE,  allowmean = T, allowdrift = T, biasadj = T,
                          lambda = Lambda, stepwise = F, approximation = F, test = "adf", ic = "aic",
                          xreg = harmonics)
```

An ARIMA(0,1,1)(2,0,0)[12] w/ errors model with fourier orders of 6 in the xreg. The Lambda is equal to -0.1.

*Note: The training time series object has been log transformed. While, no transformation has been conducted on training_hw.*

I have not found much success with any of these models so far. The one that has given my best success is the dynamic harmonic regression model as the RMSE and MAPE are lowest.

Anybody have any suggestions on what other models that I can use that might provide a better result than the models that I have built so far.